# Collection order is reversed when using map but fine with mapv

Tags: clojure

So I get results from my elasticsearch instance, that look like this:

```
{:data
 {:total 21,
  :max_score 27.479528,
  :hits
  [{:_index "statements",
    :_type "statement",
    :_id "aggregator:8888_50_1",
    :_score 27.479528,
    :_source
    {:content
     {:text "this is the only park in our city",
      :created nil,
      :author {:dgep-native true, :name "anonymous", :id 1}},
     :identifier
     {:aggregate-id "aggregator:8888", :entity-id "50", :version 1},
     :predecessors [],
     :delete-flag false,
     :references []}}
   {:_index "statements",
    :_type "statement",
    :_id "aggregator:8888_26_1",
    :_score 11.498559,
    :_source
    {:content
     {:text
      "this is based on the cats race and a little bit on the breeding",
      :created nil,
      :author {:dgep-native true, :name "anonymous", :id 1}},
     :identifier
     {:aggregate-id "aggregator:8888", :entity-id "26", :version 1},
     :predecessors [],
     :delete-flag false,
     :references []}}
   {:_index "statements",
    :_type "statement",
    :_id "aggregator:8888_52_1",
    :_score 10.234065,
    :_source
    {:content
     {:text "the city is planing a new park in the upcoming month",
      :created nil,
      :author {:dgep-native true, :name "Christian", :id 3}},
     :identifier
     {:aggregate-id "aggregator:8888", :entity-id "52", :version 1},
     :predecessors [],
     :delete-flag false,
     :references []}}
   {:_index "statements",
    :_type "statement",
    :_id "aggregator:8888_57_1",
    :_score 8.616559,
    :_source
    {:content
     {:text "the police cannot patrol in the park for 24/7",
      :created nil,
      :author {:dgep-native true, :name "anonymous", :id 1}},
     :identifier
     {:aggregate-id "aggregator:8888", :entity-id "57", :version 1},
     :predecessors [],
     :delete-flag false,
     :references []}}
   {:_index "statements",
    :_type "statement",
    :_id "aggregator:8888_56_1",
    :_score 8.005469,
    :_source
    {:content
     {:text "the rate of non-swimmers is too high",
      :created nil,
      :author {:dgep-native true, :name "anonymous", :id 1}},
     :identifier
     {:aggregate-id "aggregator:8888", :entity-id "56", :version 1},
     :predecessors [],
     :delete-flag false,
     :references []}}
   {:_index "statements",
    :_type "statement",
    :_id "aggregator:8888_29_1",
    :_score 7.8948164,
    :_source
    {:content
     {:text "this is just a claim without any justification",
      :created nil,
      :author {:dgep-native true, :name "anonymous", :id 1}},
     :identifier
     {:aggregate-id "aggregator:8888", :entity-id "29", :version 1},
     :predecessors [],
     :delete-flag false,
     :references []}}
   {:_index "statements",
    :_type "statement",
    :_id "aggregator:8888_24_1",
    :_score 5.9939632,
    :_source
    {:content
     {:text
      "the fact, that cats are capricious, is based on the cats race",
      :created nil,
      :author {:dgep-native true, :name "anonymous", :id 1}},
     :identifier
     {:aggregate-id "aggregator:8888", :entity-id "24", :version 1},
     :predecessors [],
     :delete-flag false,
     :references []}}
   {:_index "statements",
    :_type "statement",
    :_id "aggregator:8888_8_1",
    :_score 5.77637,
    :_source
    {:content
     {:text
      "you have to take the dog for a walk every day, which is tedious",
      :created nil,
      :author {:dgep-native true, :name "anonymous", :id 1}},
     :identifier
     {:aggregate-id "aggregator:8888", :entity-id "8", :version 1},
     :predecessors [],
     :delete-flag false,
     :references []}}
   {:_index "statements",
    :_type "statement",
    :_id "aggregator:8888_49_1",
    :_score 4.9624176,
    :_source
    {:content
     {:text "the number of police patrols has been increased recently",
      :created nil,
      :author {:dgep-native true, :name "anonymous", :id 1}},
     :identifier
     {:aggregate-id "aggregator:8888", :entity-id "49", :version 1},
     :predecessors [],
     :delete-flag false,
     :references []}}
   {:_index "statements",
    :_type "statement",
    :_id "aggregator:8888_37_1",
    :_score 3.8809054,
    :_source
    {:content
     {:text "we should shut down University Park",
      :created nil,
      :author {:dgep-native true, :name "Christian", :id 3}},
     :identifier
     {:aggregate-id "aggregator:8888", :entity-id "37", :version 1},
     :predecessors [],
     :delete-flag false,
     :references []}}]},
 :status :ok,
 :message "21 hit(s)"}
```

I then strip away the information I do not need in the end via
`result (get-in response [:data :hits])`.

This gives me all results, still in order.

Now I use `(map :_source res)` and the order of all elements is reversed.
If I use `(mapv :_source res)` everything is fine.

What am I missing? When I try to reproduce the behaviour with simple examples in the repl everything works fine as expected.

---

Edit: I tried the same data in a REPL. There it works as its supposed to. 
The only thing my application does is pass the data to be rendered. So maybe a problem with the rendering and a Lazyseq is forcing this bug.

---

Edit2:

This seems due to a bug in the compojure.api library. (https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/issues/412) I will close the question now.

Comment: An MCVE would really help here... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP said he would like to close it.